# encode a cmyk jpeg in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, encoding, jpeg, cmyk

I have an AIR app that saves JPEG files to the hard drive.  Currently, the jpegs are in RGB colorspace, but I am wanting them to be saved as CMYK jpegs.  Is this possible in flash?  If so, does anyone know of any libraries or examples that can help me with such a task?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think flash/flex has the ability to do this, it may need to be done on the server/desktop, we use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to perform these types of tasks.